# Missing projects properties after an update on STM32CubeIDE

Tags: eclipse, stm32cubeide

I was using version STM32CubeIDE v1.6.1 on Win 10, in which I had projects for the stm32f407g-disc1 board within the same workspace, sharing the board library. When I updated to version v1.13.1, I can no longer see the properties of the projects (right-click on each project). Same as with Alt-Enter option, and menu option project->properties.

I made clean, reindex and rebuild the projects without positive results.

any suggestions?

Comment: Are your CubeIDE setting files (in your STM32CubeIDE project directory) used in 1.6.1 now used by 1.13.1 ? Or did you delete them and let Cube regenate them ?